# regex to extract field

Tags: regex

I have one regex to extract the scriptname from a full command. It's working fine for most of the cases, but not working for the first row in sample data.

**Sample Data**

```
qcst_out_macroPlayback_13918_14112017-163000.29129.xml
qcst_mxtimingMonitoring.sh -SpecificInputLaunchers
qcst_tps_monitoring.sh -LatestDeals
```

**Output Should be**

```
macroPlayback (not working)
mxtimingMonitoring (working)
monitoring (working)
```

Regex which is not working for 1st row

```
\S+_(?<ScriptName>[^\.]+)\.\S+
```

https://regex101.com/r/cFjn85/1

Comment: What about [`^\S+_\K[a-z]+(?=[_.])`](https://regex101.com/r/Dno2Lq/2)? Note it uses the `i` modifier

Comment: Thanks but its not working for 1st and 2nd row. 
https://regex101.com/r/cFjn85/2

Comment: Please see my answer below, which explains it. You can click on the link provided and see it in use.

Comment: Great cheers !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Dno2Lq/4)

```
^\S+_\K[a-z]+
```

If `\K` is not available in your flavour of regex, you can use the following instead. This will capture the contents you are looking for into the first capture group.

```
^\S+_([a-z]+)
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at start of line
- `\S+` Match any non-whitespace character one or more times
- `_` Match the underscore character `_` literally
- `\K` Reset the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `[a-z]+` Match one or more characters in the set `a-z` (lowercase ASCII alpha characters)

**Note**: The modifiers `gmi` are used to make the regex global, multiline and case-insensitive (to match uppercase ASCII alpha characters with `[a-z]`)